# Is it better to put the click event on the html button or the parent component?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm creating a very simple button component in Angular and I was wondering if there was any difference in html semantic if I put the click event on the parent component.

Version 1:

```
<!-- template.html -->
<ui-button label="Try again" (click)="tryAgain()">
</ui-button>
```

```
// ui-button.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-button',
  templateUrl: './ui-button.component.html',
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() public label: string;
}
```

```
<!-- ui-button.component.html -->
<button>
  {{ label }}
</button>
```

Version 2:

```
<!-- template.html -->
<ui-button label="Try again" (onClickEvent)="tryAgain()">
</ui-button>
```

```
// ui-button.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'ui-button',
  templateUrl: './ui-button.component.html',
})
export class ButtonComponent {
  @Input() public label: string;
  @Output() public onClickEvent = new EventEmitter()

  public onClick(): void {
    this.onClickEvent.emit();
  }
}
```

```
<!-- ui-button.component.html -->
<button (click)="onClick()">
  {{ label }}
</button>
```

Comment: There is not much of a difference really because if necessary you will still be able to access the parent or the child element programatically, which ever way you decided to go. But normally, you would want to attach the handler directly to the element where the data (e.g., el attribute, data attribute, class name, id) is available.

Comment: instead of creating a component, maybe you should consider to create a directive that extends the original HTML button. This is because maintaining 1-1 correlation between HTML button and the custom button component is hard and tedious. 
Pls see this for reference https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

Comment: Adding click element to the parent can be useful in case you have one parent with many similar children (maybe a <ul> with lots of <li>). Instead of adding to all the <li>s, you can add to the  <ul> and inside handle the event when the current target is an <li>. This is called [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).